# Regex non-greedy exact match

Tags: python, regex

I am using a regex to find the group of strings than matches my list of prefixes exactly.

With prefixes `A, B, BB`

I can match the three groups (`Aone Atwo, BBone BBtwo, Bone Btwo`)

```
Aone
Atwo
BBone
BBtwo
Bone
Btwo
```

using the regex `^prefix[^prefix]`

But this breaks if I have the strings

```
incd
incm    
named   
namem
```

where my prefixs are `inc, name`

The `namem` is not captured. Any ideas of what I could do here?

Comment: Use a negative lookahead. `^prefix(?!prefix)`, see [a sample demo](https://regex101.com/r/X547JM/1).

Comment: Can you provide the exact regex you use?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Wow, thank you!

Comment: @Dekel Wiktor solved it, but the regex I used for for example prefix `B` would be `^B[^B]`

Comment: The regex `[^prefix]` would match exactly one character, granted it isn't `p`, `r`, `e`, `f`, `i` or `x`.

Comment: @coredump I get that now, I was completely dumbfounded, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you "negate" a single char with a negated character class, you require a char other than the one(s) defined in the class. More important thing is that you can only "negate" only a single char this way, not a *sequence* of characters.

A more universal approach is to use a negative lookahead, `(?!...)`.

```
^(?:inc|name)(?!(?:inc|name))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/X547JM/1)

- `^` - matches the string start
- `(?:inc|name)` - matches either `inc` or `name`
- `(?!(?:inc|name))` - asserts that there is no `inc` or `name` literal character *sequences* right after `inc` or `name`

Comment: Sorry for a late additional question, but if I add `BBBoot` to my first list of strings, then `^BB(?!BB)` matches this addition, can I avoid this as well?

Comment: (if I change the regex to `^BB(?!B)` I correctly eliminate this match, but I am unsure if this generalises)

Comment: Not sure what the scenario is. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/u8CoHc/1), `BBBot` is not matched since `B` is still restricting the `BB` from matching before another `B`.